# C++ Multi-threading?

Tags: c++, multithreading

I've decided to make a game in C++ recently and I figured out that there isn't multi-threading support in C++ :( There are libraries but they are platform dependent and that's not really good. Is there any way to do this platform-independent in C++?

Comment: openmp, tbb ....................

Comment: why not pthread library?

Comment: @0x90 is pthread supported well in windows?

Comment: of course not... who uses windows??? didn't know there is a cross platform multi-threaded library...

Comment: @0x90 99% of all PC gamers roughly. No matter how much you like other OS'es, for PC games you really can't make your way around Windows nowadays.

Comment: @Cubic: Although there is an implementation of pthreads for windows... but I would not go as far as recommending it.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

C++11 has built-in threading support (as part of the language as well as the standard library).

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C%2B%2B11#Multithreading_memory_model

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C%2B%2B11#Threading_facilities

Also, boost::thread (boost::asio I believe) does offer (more or less) platform independent threading support (and it's not the only library that offers this).

Comment: I believe [tbb](http://threadingbuildingblocks.org/) provide more facilities - like those concurrent containers

Comment: @lzprgmr, tbb is license encumbered.

Comment: @lucas1024 no, it's not. Well, it uses the same license as GNU libstdc++, which equates to: link to whatever you like.

Comment: I still read this as license encumbered; the link points to a license that basically says it's GPLv2, but may be linked to "free software". They might be a bit more flexible what "free" means, but you still have to get the commercial license in some cases.

Comment: boost::asio does not provide threading. It does have a design (http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_51_0/doc/html/boost_asio/overview/core/async.html) that can benefit from multithreading, but it does not provide multithreading itself.